# Get a specific Item in an ArrayList in a List Java

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

I have this code in Java. I am working on an android project, but this is strictly Java.

```
List<Group> groupsearch = null;
groupsearch = ((GroupApi)api).getMyGroup(sm.getCurrentSession().ID);

//groupsearch returns a nested Arraylist  of items e.g 
groupsearch[0] = group[0]= {companies: datacom; groupname: skype, datecreated: july 2014}
groupsearch[1] = group[1] = {companies: bittorrent; groupname: yahoo, datecreated: july 2014
```

I want to be able to search through the `List<Group> groupsearch` and check if the string input `newgroupname` already exists in the `List`.

```
List<Group> groupsearch = null; 
GroupApi api = new GroupApi(context);
try {
    groupsearch = ((GroupApi)api).getMyGroup(sm.getCurrentSession().ID);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
for (int i =0; i<groupsearch.size(); i++ )
{
    if(groupsearch.get(i).toString().equals(etNewGroupName.getText().toString()))
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Group Has Already Been Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }

//etNewGroupName is the input text
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What does `Group.toString()` look like, because that's what you're currently checking the new group name against. If `Group` looks anything sensible, it will have some sort of method that looks like `getGroupName()` which gives you access to the group name of that particular item. Sounds to me like that's what you should be checking against. (this is pretty basic Java stuff btw)

Comment: I think you need to use Set instead of List.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

By looking at the lines

```
groupsearch[0] = group[0]= {companies: datacom; groupname: skype, datecreated: july 2014}
groupsearch[1] = group[1] = {companies: bittorrent; groupname: yahoo, datecreated: july 2014
```

I believe the Group object stores a Key,Value pair. Its a Map.

In your code, instead of `List<Group> groupsearch` , use `ArrayList<Group> groupsearch`. Its a more concrete implementation of the List interface.
Then iterate through the arraylist `groupsearch`. On each iteration, the object that you will get is a **Map**. Further search in this **Map** for the **Value** `etNewGroupName` based on the **Key** `groupname`.
It should work.

Comment: Changing `List` to `ArrayList` won't change the implementation returned by `getMyGroup`

Comment: Also, why did you say its a `Map`? The Op has already said its a `Group` object.

Comment: @TedTrippin The group object returns values in the form of Key,Value pair. `{companies: datacom; groupname: skype, datecreated: july 2014}`. Thus I said its probably a map. Though the actual structure of the Group object is not displayed in the snippet

Comment: How do you know this? The Op hasn't said. They've merely serialised the data to make it visible. Anyway, your misunderstanding of List/ArrayList shows a very large whole in your java knowledge.